# Dilog not working in android apllication

Tags: java, android

I am having two classes `SqlLiteExample.java`and `HotOrNot.java`.First one is for creating interface and second one is for Database creation.

*SqlLiteExample.java*

```
package com.thenewboston;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SqlLiteExample extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
EditText etName,etHotness;
Button btnSave,btnView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sqliteexample);
        etName=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        etName=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        btnSave=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSQLUPDATE);
        btnView=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSQLVIEW);
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch(v.getId()){

        case R.id.btnSQLUPDATE:
            boolean didItWork=true;
            try{
        String name=etName.getText().toString();
        String hotness=etHotness.getText().toString();
        HotOrNot entry= new HotOrNot(SqlLiteExample.this);
        entry.open();
        entry.createEntry(name,hotness);
        entry.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
                didItWork= false;
            }finally{
                if(didItWork){
                    Dialog d= new Dialog(this);
                    d.setTitle("Heck yea");
                    System.out.println("testing");
                    TextView tv= new TextView(this);
                    tv.setText("sucess");
                    d.setContentView(tv);
                    d.show();
                }
            }


        break;
        case R.id.btnSQLVIEW:

        break;
        }

    }


}
```

*HotOrNot.java*

```
package com.thenewboston;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class HotOrNot {
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "persons_name";
    public static final String KEY_HOTNESS = "persons_hotness";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "HotOrNotdb";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "peopleTable";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private DbHelper ourhelper;
    private final Context ourContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

    private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ROWID
                    + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_NAME
                    + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_HOTNESS + "TEXT NOT NULL);"

            );
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST "+ DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);

        }

    }

    public HotOrNot(Context c) {
        ourContext = c;
    }
    public HotOrNot open() throws SQLException{
        ourhelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
        ourDatabase= ourhelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }
    public void close(){
        ourhelper.close();
    }
    public long createEntry(String name, String hotness) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ContentValues cv= new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_NAME, name);
        cv.put(KEY_HOTNESS, hotness);
        return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

    }
}
```

Problem in that whenever I press `btnSave` is should display a dilog which is defined in `finally` block of `case R.id.btnSQLUPDATE:`but it is not.I have tried to debug the code,after executing `HotOrNot entry= new HotOrNot(SqlLiteExample.this);` in the same `case` it is moving into catch block and catches exception.I am uable find where I am doing wrong.

Comment: `KEY_HOTNESS + "TEXT NOT NULL);"` you need to add a **SPACE** before `TEXT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got NPL(null pointer exeption) in this line:

```
String hotness=etHotness.getText().toString();
```

you did not findViewById "etHotness" , look at your code:
in `onCreate()` you write this:

```
etName=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
etName=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
```

shoud change to:

```
etName=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
etHotness=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use AlertDialog, it's better solution. Use this code:

```
   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

            View viewDialog = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alertdialog_gameover, null);
            TextView title = (TextView)viewDialog.findViewById(R.id.title);
            title.setText("Successfully");

            builder.setView(viewDialog)
                    .setPositiveButton("Play again", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                           //Set something for positive

                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                           //set something for negative
                        }
                    });
            //create dialog
            builder.create();
//show dialog
            builder.show();
```

**Edit:**

try to change:

```
}catch(Exception e){
                didItWork= false;
            }
```

to:

```
}catch(Exception e){
                didItWork= true;
            }
```

your code for Dialog work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I personnally use AlertDialog with AlertDialog.Builder for this kind of situation. Works pretty well...

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("Your title")
    .setMessage("Your message")
    .setPositiveButton("OK", mOnClickListener)
    .create()
    .show();
```

You can also set a list of clickable item as view, or a list of checkboxes or radiobuttons with methods setAdapter, setSingleChoiceItems and setMultiChoiceItems. I find it simplier to use.